# Clocking in system PHP, Ajax, Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm attempting to write some code that enables my colleagues to clock in/out. 
Firstly, they select the month they are born, then all names appear for that month. This data is retrieved from a DB.

That all works with this code (I got the majority from this site) - (index.html) (This part works, and will show the correct list of users based on month from the DB.

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","show.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<h3 align="center">To clock in / out please select the month you were born</h3>
  <div class="wrapper">         
  <div class="row top-buffer">          
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="January" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="February" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="March" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="April" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="May" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="June" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    </div>
  <div class="row top-buffer">          
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="July" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="August" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="September" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">        
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="October" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="November" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <input class="btn col-md-2" value="December" type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
```

However, when they select their name, I need it to call a PHP file which writes that name back to a linked database.

show.php -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(){
var fullname=$("#submit").val();
$.ajax({
                    url:"insert.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:fullname,
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                       window.location.href = url;  
                   }
                });
                });
                });
</script>



</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = ($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('x','x','x','x');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"xxx");
$sql="SELECT * FROM clock WHERE month = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\"><input type=\"Submit\" id=\"submit\" value= '". $row['fullname'] ."' name=\"submit\" ></div>" ;

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
```

From my tests, pressing their name this isn't calling insert.php at all. let alone sending the name value. It is however refreshing the page.

A lot of the code has been produced using answers to different questions, and using my limited coding knowledge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have multiple elements on the page with the same ID. This won't work. You're also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks; that database code is unsafe. And why is your first Ajax request not using jQuery like your second one is?

Comment: Also you're not sending anything usable in your POST request. And you can't just send back jQuery code in your Ajax response and expect it to work. All the client-side code needs to be on your first page, and event handlers should be added by the callback of the initial GET request.

Comment: Rather than just copying and pasting things that you don't understand, I'd strongly recommend getting an understanding of how this stuff works before starting over again.

Answer (score -1):

Use preventdefault(); this will prevent the default form action or refreshing page.

```
  $("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventdefault()
    var fullname=$("#submit").val();
    $.ajax({
             url:"insert.php",
             type:"POST",
             data:fullname,
             success:function(data){
              alert(data);
              window.location.href = url;  
            }
           });
         });
     });
```